# Dispatching Pathfinding on a separate thread issues

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, pointers, path-finding

**Problem**

A* Pathfinding Technique Used

I'm mid development of a game. The pathfinding is fairly optimised. However, I've had to adjust it to account for over/under tiles which has added a significant increase in the looping when accounting for neighbours of tiles.

So as a quick fix, I've decided to perform the pathfinding on another thread to stop the freezing in the game it self.

However, now when it's pathfinding, through debugging I've noticed it'll develop a path - then mid path, it'll move to a neighbour that isn't possible. as if it loses it's memory for a current location and goes back to an original location or so.

It's a bit hard to provide the code to the problem as there's so much code it's not even fathomable to locate the exact issue, I believe it's a memory issue or a pointer losing it's data.

**Code Snippets**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self generateRandomPathForPlayer:player];
});

-(void)generateRandomPathForPlayer:(PlayerClass *)player {

    if (!player.dead) {

        int x = [self returnRandomNumberBetween:1 to:map.width];
        int y = [self returnRandomNumberBetween:1 to:map.height];

        for (Tile *block in self.children) {
            if ([block isKindOfClass:[Tile class]]) {
                if (CGPointEqualToPoint(block.point, CGPointMake(x, y))) {
                    if (block.blocked) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        NSArray *path = [self findPathFrom:player.currentPoint to:block.point];

                        for (int i = 0; i < [path count]; i++) {
                            HSAIPathFindingNode *node = [path objectAtIndex:i];

                            [player.playerPath addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:node.point]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

-(NSArray*)findPathFrom:(CGPoint)start to:(CGPoint)end{

    HSAIPathFinding *pathFinder = [[HSAIPathFinding alloc] init];
    pathFinder.delegate = self;
    pathFinder.heuristic = [HSAIPathFindingHeuristic diagonalHeuristic];

    return [pathFinder findPathFrom: start to: end];; // returns an array of HSAIPathFindingNodes
}
```

An example of the log for the path (at fault) would be:

```
2016-10-01 14:13:45.734 pathfinding[2725:244756] (
"NSPoint: {12, 2}",
"NSPoint: {13, 3}",
"NSPoint: {14, 3}",
"NSPoint: {15, 3}",
"NSPoint: {16, 3}",
"NSPoint: {17, 3}",
"NSPoint: {18, 3}",
"NSPoint: {19, 3}",
"NSPoint: {10, 2}",
"NSPoint: {11, 3}",
"NSPoint: {11, 4}",
"NSPoint: {11, 5}",
"NSPoint: {11, 6}",
"NSPoint: {11, 7}",
"NSPoint: {11, 8}",
"NSPoint: {11, 9}",
"NSPoint: {11, 10}",
"NSPoint: {11, 11}",
"NSPoint: {11, 12}",
"NSPoint: {11, 13}",
"NSPoint: {11, 14}",
"NSPoint: {11, 15}",
"NSPoint: {11, 16}",
"NSPoint: {12, 17}",
"NSPoint: {12, 18}",
"NSPoint: {12, 19}",
"NSPoint: {13, 20}",
"NSPoint: {13, 21}",
"NSPoint: {13, 22}",
"NSPoint: {13, 23}",
"NSPoint: {13, 24}",
"NSPoint: {12, 25}",
"NSPoint: {11, 26}",
"NSPoint: {11, 27}",
"NSPoint: {11, 28}",
"NSPoint: {10, 2}",
"NSPoint: {11, 3}",
"NSPoint: {11, 4}",
"NSPoint: {11, 5}",
"NSPoint: {12, 6}",
"NSPoint: {13, 7}",
"NSPoint: {13, 8}",
"NSPoint: {13, 9}",
"NSPoint: {13, 10}",
"NSPoint: {14, 11}",
"NSPoint: {15, 12}",
"NSPoint: {15, 13}",
"NSPoint: {15, 14}",
"NSPoint: {15, 15}",
"NSPoint: {15, 16}",
"NSPoint: {16, 17}",
"NSPoint: {17, 18}",
"NSPoint: {18, 19}",
"NSPoint: {19, 20}",
"NSPoint: {19, 21}",
"NSPoint: {20, 22}",
"NSPoint: {21, 23}",
"NSPoint: {22, 24}",
"NSPoint: {23, 24}",
"NSPoint: {24, 24}",
"NSPoint: {25, 24}",
"NSPoint: {26, 24}",
"NSPoint: {27, 24}",
"NSPoint: {28, 24}",
"NSPoint: {29, 25}",
"NSPoint: {29, 26}",
"NSPoint: {29, 27}",
"NSPoint: {28, 28}",
"NSPoint: {27, 28}",
"NSPoint: {26, 28}",
"NSPoint: {25, 29}"
)
```

Comment: If it's a threading issue rather than a simple pathfinding bug, probably you aren't locking the memory properly for use by multiple threads, so something changes in some other thread that affects the pathfinding thread.

Comment: @WarrenDew Yeah, I still haven't found it yet mind.. Absolute nightmare.